# Write a Sine-Deriving Machine

Tags: code-golf, calculus, trigonometry

#### The Challenge

Your challenge is to write a program that evaluates the following function:

f(x, t) = d^x / dt^x (sin t)

That is, the x-th derivative of sin t. In case you aren't familiar with calculus, here is a table of derivatives for the sine function:

...

f(-1, t) = -cos t

f(0, t) = sin t

f(1, t) = cos t

f(2, t)= -sin  t

...

The sequence repeats these 4 functions.

#### The Inputs

Your program should take in an integer to be used as the x value in the function, and a float to be used at the t value in the function.

Your program may use radians or degrees for the sine function.

#### The Output

Your program should output the value of f(x, t) given the integer x and float t.

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Are you sure d^-1 / dt^-1 (sin t) = -cos t ?

Comment: What precision should this be to?

Comment: Test cases would be great.

Comment: Okay so trigonometry builtins seem to be allowed.
Just a comment, who is not familiar with calculus does not understand the table either :P

Comment: Today, I am more in the mood of writing an exponential function `e^x` deriving machine.

Comment: I think you should repeat the challenge forbidding the π/2 left shift technique!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Actually, 5 bytes

```
╦*½+S
```

[Try it online](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=4pWmKsK9K1M&input=MAox)

Takes input as `t\nx`.

Explanation:

```
╦*½+S
╦*     pi*n
  ½    half that
   +   add t
    S  sine
```

Answer (score 10):

### Python, 42 bytes

```python
from math import*
lambda x,n:sin(x+pi/2*n)
```

Uses the fact that differentiating shifts the function by `pi/2` left.

Comment: I'm such an idiot

Answer (score 6):

## C (gcc), 30 bytes

```
#define f(x,n)sin(x+n*acos(0))
```

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 16 bytes

```haskell
x%n=sin$x+pi/2*n
```

Defines a binary operator `%`.

```haskell
λ 2.0 % (-3)
-0.4161468365471426
```

Uses the fact that differentiating shifts the function by `pi/2` left.

Making it point-free was longer (takes `n x`):

```haskell
(sin.).(+).(pi/2*)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Convex (IDE version only), 6 bytes

```
P½*+ms
```

[Try it online!](http://convex.tryitonline.net/#code=aVxpXFDCvSorbXM&input=&args=NA+NQ)

After futher investigation, with the help of Dennis in chat, it was found that the command-line version of Convex (what TIO uses) has a bug that breaks the code (the link above contains a workaround). However, the IDE version of Convex, avaliable on GitHub before the challenge was posted, does not have this bug. Here is a link to the IDE version that was avaliable before the challenge was posted: [Convex IDE](https://github.com/GamrCorps/Convex/blob/a1cc4af43bcb9246b4a988615205722b54bc29bc/out/builds/convex-dev/convex_ide/convex-ide.jar).

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica 14 bytes

With help from Martin Ender,

```
Sin[#2+Pi/2#]&
```

Comment: Shouldn't `x` be `#2`?

Comment: At the same time, you don't need the `*`, so you'll end up with the same byte count.

Answer (score 2):

## J, 17 bytes

```j
4 :'1&o.d.(4|x)y'
```

Computes the (x%4)th derivative of sine, and then apply to right argument.

### Usage:

```j
>> f =: 4 :'1&o.d.(4|x)y'
>> _1 0 1 2 3 (f"0 0) 0
<< _1 0 1 0 _1
```

where `>>` is STDIN and `<<` is STDOUT.

Comment: Why do you need to compute the `(x%4)`? Wouldn't it be simpler to just use the `x`th derivative?  (Not a `J` user so this might be a stupid question)

Comment: @StevenH. Because stupid question requires negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 17 bytes

```julia
x\t=x*π/2+t|>sin
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=eFx0PXgqz4AvMit0fD5zaW4KCmZvciAoeCwgdCkgaW4gKCgwLCDPgC82KSwgKDEsIM-ALzYpLCAoMiwgz4AvNiksICgzLCDPgC82KSkKICAgIEBwcmludGYoIiUxMS44ZlxuIiwgeFx0KQplbmQ&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## C (gcc), <del>53</del> <del>46</del> 45 bytes

```c
#import<math.h>
#define f(x,n)sin(x+M_PI/2*n)
```

Probably Ideone doesn't have glibc, says `M_PI` is undeclared.

Comment: `M_PI` is __not__ in `math.h`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007925/using-m-pi-with-c89-standard.

Comment: But...it's there on glibc? https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=math/math.h;h=2f77deec87707721ed677def6e29341c9f9d3a06;hb=HEAD#l406

Comment: Not in "C", the language you specified in the top of your answer. C as implemented by gcc has it, so you can write "C (gcc)", but C is a language defined by an abstract standard, and makes no mention of `M_PI`.

Answer (score 1):

### R, 26 bytes

```
function(t,x)sin(t+pi/2*x)
```

Exactly what it says on the tin...

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 29 bytes

```
x=>t=>Math.sin(t+Math.PI/2*x)
```

Usage:

```
f=x=>t=>Math.sin(t+Math.PI/2*x)
f(x)(t)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Lua 5.x, 37 bytes

```lua
x,n=...return math.sin(x+math.pi/2*n)
```

usage:

```lua
> print(loadfile('sine.lua')(1,0))
0.8414709848079
> print(loadfile('sine.lua')(math.pi,0))
1.2246467991474e-16
> print(loadfile('sine.lua')(math.pi,1))
-1.0
> print(loadfile('sine.lua')(math.pi,2))
-2.4492935982947e-16
> print(loadfile('sine.lua')(math.pi,3))
1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

### Matlab, 19 bytes

```
@(x,t)sin(t+x*pi/2)
```

Comment: So why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

## [SQF](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/SQF_syntax), 29 bytes

Using the file-as-a-function format:

```
params["x","y"];sin(x+pi/2*y)
```

Call as `[x, t] call NAME_OF_COMPILED_FUNCTION`

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 25 bytes

```
INPUT X,N?SIN(X+N*PI()/2)
```

Probably shorter in some BASIC dialect that has a constant named `PI` rather than `PI()`. (Yes, `PI()` is not actually a function, those parentheses are a lie.)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
žq*;+Å½
```

Port of [*@Mego♦*'s Actually answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89741/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L5CLWvtw62H9v7/b8xlAAA) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9vc2FiaWX/NSg1xbjDo3Z5PyIg4oaSICI/eWD/xb5xKjsrw4XCvf8s/w).

**Explanation:**

```python
žq        # Push PI
  *       # Multiply it with the first (implicit) input `t`
   ;      # Halve it
    +     # Add the second (implicit) input `x`
     Å½   # Take the Sine of that (and output it implicitly)
```